# Change image src onmouseover div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change src of img when onmouseover that div-12. How can I achieve that?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <a href="{{ action('') }}" id="link-settings" href="">
     <div id="block-settings" class="col-xs-2 button-left-premium">
        <img class="button-img" src="{{ asset('/img.png') }}"></img>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xs-5 button-right-premium" id="block-settings-two">
     <h3 class="settings-title" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">test</h3>
   </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: Hey friend, can you please give it a try yourself and then show us what you tried? PS... "How to" is a statement, not a question :)

Comment: I tried a lot of times but js is not my good skill..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

Via JQuery, we add a listener to the hover event of the `col-md-12` div and change the src attribute to the image

```js
$('.col-md-12').hover(function() {
  original = $('.button-img').attr('src');
  $('.button-img').attr('src', 'img2.jpg');
}, function() {
  $('.button-img').attr('src', original);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 5px;">
    <a href="{{ action('') }}" id="link-settings" href="">
      <div id="block-settings" class="col-xs-2 button-left-premium">
        <img class="button-img" src="{{ asset('/img.png') }}"></img>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 button-right-premium" id="block-settings-two">
        <h3 class="settings-title" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">test</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: how to change it back after nohover?

Comment: @Promgrma edited to return to original image. Those this help ??

Comment: @Promgrma did it work for you. Or did you ran into any problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
const div = document.querySelector('your-div');
const img = document.querySelector('your-img');
div.onmouseover = () => img.src = 'your src';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JS:

```
let a = document.getElementById('a');
let b = document.getElementById('b');

a.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    let newSrc = '/b.jpg';

    if (a.getAttribute('src') !== newSrc) {
        a.src = newSrc;
    }
})
```